# Android configChanges for orientation

Tags: android

I need to prevent restarting the activity when the user changes the orientation, so I need to set:

> android:configChanges="orientation"

But in the document, there this a note on orientation,

> Note: If your application targets Android 3.2 (API level 13) or
>   higher, then you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration,
>   because it also changes when a device switches between portrait and
>   landscape orientations.

I'm a little afraid of using with **screenSize** together because I only need that for orientation.

I'd like to know when the screenSize event will occur?

I set 'orientation|screenSize' together and tested with changing device's font size, but the screenSize is not changed so the activity has been reloaded.

When(in what case) the screenSize event will be called? and is there any side effects if I set the screenSize to configChanges?

Comment: Without knowing exactly why you need this behavior: Please note that an activity can be restarted not only through an orientation change. Usually it is bad form of trying to prevent the activity to be restarted. You should design your app in such a way that the activity can be restarted at any time. The Android developer documentation has [some good tips](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) on how to handle this.

Comment: I understand it is not good form. but I'd like to know is there any known side effects? and something I can test before setting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the Android source code for this. The interesting bits are in [ActivityRecord](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java) method `crossesSizeThreshold` and `getConfigurationChanges`. The `screenSize` event occurs when the dimensions of the screen changes and the change might be "important" for the application. So what does "important" mean:

When a screen resize happens for an app, Android tries to decide if the activity needs to be relaunched. If the size change is small a re-layout of the activity content might be enough, while for a bigger resize a full configuration change needs to occur.

To decide if the configuration change has to occur Android collects the app's size-sensitive resource qualifiers (e.g. `layout-h400dp`). If the resize crosses a qualifier boundary a configuration change occurs, while if the resize does not cross the boundary the activity is kept and only a re-layout gets executed.

Having said that, I tried to reproduce this behavior. I couldn't come up with a conclusive test because other `configChanges` events happened during the resize too.

My initial point still stands. It's hard to predict all possible reasons why a configuration change might occur and trying to prevent the recreation of the activity is very difficult to do. Especially with the amount of API versions and device models we have today. A well architected app that separates business logic and state from the UI layer, is still the way to go.